# realsense2_camera: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [librealsense2]

Tags: ros, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I am trying to install the realsense2_camera package on ROS Noetic. I have installed the librealsense libraries following this [tutorial](https://github.com/acrobotic/Ai_Demos_RPi/wiki/Raspberry-Pi-4-and-Intel-RealSense-D435), and the realsense viewer work for me.

The problem comes when I try to resolve the dependencies of the package realsense2_camera. The following error appears:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/catkin_ws $ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
realsense2_camera: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [librealsense2]
Continuing to install resolvable dependencies...
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

I saw that other user have the same problems but in other version of ROS, but the solutions didn't work for me. What can I do to solve the issue?

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364033/realsense2_camera:-cannot-locate-rosdep-definition-for-%5Blibrealsense2%5D/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2020-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First you have to install the librealsense libraries from repository: https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense
Then installing `apt-get install ros-noetic-realsense2_camera` it works smoothly.

---

Originally posted by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) with karma: 113 on 2021-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0